# How do I solve this inhomogeneous linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dt} = 2y + 3e^{-t}$

I tried to lookup how to solve an inhomogeneous differential equation, but haven't found a clear answer to it.

Comment: Integrating Factor, Exact Equation, LaPlace Transform...

Answer (score 0):

You have the equation $y'-2y=3e^{-t}$, so use the integrating factor $\mu=e^{-2t}$ to rewrite the equation as $(y\mu)'=3\mu e^{-t}$. Then you can simply integrate the right hand side with respect to $t$ and then divide by $\mu$ to solve explicitly for $y$.

Note that in general, for an equation $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$ with continuous $p,g$ on the interval of existence, the integrating factor is $\mu=\exp(\int p(t)dt)$ so that you can rewrite the equation as $(y\mu)'=\mu g(t)$.